# Nginx - reverse proxy a Ghost blog with /subfolder redirect

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

I have a working nginx instance with the rules below. But I'm having difficulties pointing all the requests to domain.com/ghost

I tried modifying the `location / {}` block to `location /ghost/ {}` but with no success. I just get a 404 from the ghost app. Any suggestions?

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home//user/ghost/;
    index index.php;

   # if ($http_host != "domain.com") {
   #      rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri permanent;
   # }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ttf|woff)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, mustrevalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a regexp `location` directive for a similar proxy setup. This is the *minified* configuration file:

```
worker_processes  1;
pid               /path/to/file.pid;
worker_priority   15;

events {
    worker_connections 512;
    accept_mutex        on;
}

http {
    server {
        error_log   /path/to/log/error.log error;
        listen      127.0.0.1:9000;
        server_name example.com;

        location ~* (/ghost) {
           expires epoch;
           proxy_no_cache 1;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this, (changing the proxy_pass listening port) but I get a 404. Would it be possible to share the entire config you are using? Maybe I'm missing something..

Comment: There is nothing special, just the usual proxy directives. I don't have root nor index directives. Have you checked ghost logs? The 404 is from ghost or from nginx?

Comment: It's ghost's 404. This is the config I used (the rest is as in the code I posted above):
`location ~* (/ghostblog) {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
}
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ttf|woff)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, mustrevalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
}`

Comment: Updated the answer with a minimal configuration file. It works as-is on my site.

Comment: I updated the virtual host config in /sites-enabled with the directive from you (only the server block, the rest was similar with what I have in nginx.conf). However now, when I try to `npm start` I get a conflict that seems to suggest the port is already in use `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`

Comment: Yes, the port is being used. Stop/start properly. Or just reload.

Comment: Thanks for the support, much appreciated. It refused to work, even after restart, so I ended up setting it with sub-domains, as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198965/serving-multiple-node-apps-with-nginx-on-same-domain)

Comment: if it's the port that seems to be already in use, try this:
    $ fuser -k 80/tcp

Answer (score 1):

Have solved similar problem with other apps which have no support for subfolders. Both apps are built on one platform, so they both tries to work in /fx dir. I had to place one of them in to subfolder /gpms .

The idea is to redirect requests with referer from subfolder to destinations which links outside of subfolder - i just add subfolder to beginning of such uris. It is not ideal, but it works.

Here is my nginx config:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /fx/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:56943/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }

     error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
     set $if_and_hack "";
     if ( $http_referer ~ '^http://mydomain.com/gpms/.*$' ) {
        set $if_and_hack "refgpms";
        }
     if ( $uri !~ '^/gpms/.*$' ) {
        set $if_and_hack "${if_and_hack}_urinogpms";
     }
     if ( $if_and_hack = "refgpms_urinogpms" ) {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$ http://$host/gpms/$1;
        }

    location /gpms/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cookie_path  /fx /;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12788/fx/;
    proxy_redirect     default;
    }
}
```

External links will be broken, but it is not critical for me and i guess it may be corrected.

$if_and_hack is for overcome nginx limitation on nested conditions.

By the way i have got a cookies issue, because they was set with path, and hit browser bug with not sending cookies for a new path after redirect, so i just remove path from cookies.

Note full link form in rewrite - this form of rewrite immediately redirects browser to new page, you should not change it to just "/gpms/$1".

As alternative, i guess, it may be possible to use [nginx module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule) to inspect html content and modify links. I have not tried this. Or consider to use subdomains instead of subfolders.

Answer (score -1):

Good news! As of version 0.4.0 Ghost now supports [subdirectory installation](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Release-Notes%3a-0.4.0#subdirectory-support). And there are already [people who've figured this out and created tutorials](http://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/).

Comment: The first link is dead.